# '==' works locally but '=' required for comparison on server

Tags: javascript, meteor

I couldnt figure out why my Meteor template helper wasnt working on my Ubuntu server, so I just hacked together a couple variations and this one ended up working...locally I use `if(user[0].trusted == true)` but for some reason that conditional wasnt getting triggered on the server.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isTrusted', function(user_id){
        var user = Meteor.users.find({_id: user_id}).fetch();

        console.log(user, 'user');
        console.log(user[0].trusted);

        if(user[0].trusted = true){
            console.log(user[0].trusted, 'user trusted field');
            return true;
        } else {
            false;
        }

});
```

Why?

Comment: and all you are doing is assigning true to the property which will evaluate to true. That if is not checking that trusted is true.

Comment: = will not work for comparisons either... == compares and type casts, === does straight comparison as if same type

Comment: `if(user[0].trusted = true){ }` is equivalent to `user[0].trusted = true; if (true) { }`.

Comment: @humble.rumble that's exactly what I said... In different words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hack is wrong. It will always enter in the if branch, mostly because you are not comparing but assigning:

```
if(user[0].trusted = true)
```

Here you are assigning to user[0].trusted the true value. Because it's inside an if, javascript is checking if the assignment is correct. Because it assigned correctly, then it enters in the branch (**always**).

Send to console the value of user[0].trusted. Maybe it's a number, or has another value. Anyway, your code has a bug, it's not a thing with the server.

Comment: in the server db I cast the value of `trusted` as a string as opposed to a boolean

Answer (score 1):

This may be a nice way to do it too:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isTrusted', function(user_id){
    return !!Meteor.users.findOne({_id: user_id, trusted: true});
});
```

Or if you cast it to a string you can use `'true'` instead of `true`

Comment: using ! ! returns a boolean as opposed to an object ?

Comment: answer found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript